# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class - ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have form where a user submit a e-mail, its in the view: `views/about/home.html.haml`

The form looks like this:

```
 = form_for @waitinglist do |f|
   = f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email", autofocus: :true
   = button_tag class: "btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary sigin-button" do
     %p Put me on the waiting list
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class WaitinglistsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new(params[:waitinglist])
    if @waitinglist.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render action: :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.new
  end
end
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Waitinglist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

But I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

What is wrong?

Comment: should work.. please post some more code

Comment: You have to define `@waitinglist` in the controller action corresponding to `views/about/home.html.haml`.

Comment: @Mischa You mean in the about controller? what should I define their?

Comment: Yes, if that has the action that renders `views/about/home.html.haml` then you have to define `@waitinglist` there. You should add `@waitinglist = Waitinglist.new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
@waitinglist = Waitinglist.new
```

in the `home` method of your `AboutController`. Your form tries to use `@waitinglist`, but if you don't define it it will be `nil` and this exception will be thrown.